# How to use static Objective-C frameworks in a CocoaPod written in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header, static-framework

I have a CocoaPod written in Swift 4. Now I need to add some new features to this pod. To be able to do it I need to use a static framework written in Objective-C.

I supposed I need to use a bridging header, but I don't know how should I modify my .podspec in such case. When I am trying to add a header file with this line of code:

```
#import <MyObjectiveCFramework/MyObjectiveCFramework.h>
```

to `s.source_files` I see this error: **Include of non-modular header inside framework module**.

Also, I found out that I can use a special module.modulemap file, but what data should I add to that file and how can I refer to the module.modulemap in my .podspec file?

Comment: E.g. if `MyObjectiveCFramework` has it own pod file, you may add to swift `podspec` file row like `s.dependency 'MyObjectiveCFramework'`

Comment: I added `MyObjectiveCFramework` as `s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyObjectiveCFramework.framework'`

Comment: @gaRik I can use MyObjectiveCFramework in a Swift project if I add `#import <MyObjectiveCFramework/MyObjectiveCFramework.h>` to a bridging file, but how to do it in a CocoaPod?

Comment: anyone was able to resolve it? Facing the same issue.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 No, just asked the library's provider to wrap it into a pod.